# Suspend sockets connection on applicationWillResignActive or applicationDidEnterBackground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, websocket

I'm wondering which is the right delegate to suspend the sockets connection to resume it later and why.

From what I've read and seen in other projects that used sockets, `applicationWillResignActive` seems to be the right one, but I've also noticed that it's being called quite too often. (Even when showing the "Itunes InApp" purchase dialog)

I wouldn't like to close connection when it's unnecessary. As far as I'm concerned, on Active state, the application is still able to handle sockets so there shouldn't be a problem if I close connection when app enters background instead, but I wouldn't like app to just go to background without making sure connection is properly closed and miss messages on the process.

Same happens when resuming connection. As of now it's on the `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate but maybe it makes more sense to be on `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Are there any reasons to use this delegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

So, seeing as nobody is answering I feel I should add some response from what I have discovered based on further testing so this questions is not left unanswered.

Basically it makes more sense to suspend/close connection when app goes background and resume/reconnect when app enters foreground.

The reasoning behind this is that applicationWillResignActive will happen too often and even when the socket connection can still kept open. When receiving any alert, a call or activating  the multitask, but the app is still alive and fully operational.

This also means that, if you work with in-app purchases, when you are prompted to enter your iTunes details, connection will be close, this can be a problem if you are also managing those purchases with your own backend and need the connection alive.

From what I've seen, when the app enters background is when socket connection cannot be kept alive anymore and should be safe to just close it on applicationDidEnterBackground instead.

As a side note, remember to make sure connection is properly closed as you only have approximately 5 seconds to do whatever you need here, specially if you are listening to a socket close event to do some stuff.

Again, this is from my experience. If you have more information on this matter feel free to let me know.